# Execute Node command on button click

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a web application and on button click I want to run node command.
Instead of executing node command on command line, trying to execute it on click of button from front end.
ex:-
I have a web application and on button click I want to run node command.
Instead of executing node command on command line, trying to execute it on click of button from front end.

ex:

```
$( ".button_class" ).on( "click", function() {
   //execute command like : node app.js
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not run node command line on client side as you mention. But alternatively you can make api and hit that api on button click. In that api you can run commnad with.

I am giving you link. that can help you to run command line with node.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd

Answer (score 1):

Use the package called `node-cmd`, install it with npm `npm i node-cmd`.
Documentation link: [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd)